# UISearchBar box color

Tags: ios, ios7, colors, searchbar

I have a search bar and beside that i want a button with the same background color as the one in search bar. Does anyone know this color?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its #A4A4A4
Or you could try the Eyedropper tool in photoshop

Answer (score 0):

Just customize the text field itself.

I am simply doing this and it works fine for me (iOS 7).

```
UITextField *txfSearchField = [_searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
txfSearchField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This way you don't need to create an image, size it, etc...

without using private API's:

```
for (UIView* subview in [[self.searchBar.subviews lastObject] subviews]) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)subview;
        [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
```